# set div color when page loads using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Please check my attached image. In this image three rows are showing. These three row values (language name) are getting from database. Each language has different ranking. I need to show color variation in each div 
In my table. I have a ranking field it's value is 1 to 5. Please check my demo also. I have getting ranking values from table `rankingColor = item.ranking;` How can I add colors for each div using ranking values?

[image]

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/30/)

**js**

```
//Dummy data for this test
var responseDB = {
    selectLanguageRankingTagId: [{
        id: "1",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "English",
        ranking: "2",
        title_en: "English"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "German",
        ranking: "3",
        title_en: "German"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "French",
        ranking: "4",
        title_en: "French"
    }

    ]
}

$.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
        rankingColor = item.ranking;
        // add the row to the user-language-data div
        $( ".loadDefaultUserLanguage" ).append('<div class="col-md-8" id="del-user-language_' + item.id + '" style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 40px; margin:5px 0px; padding-top:10px;"><div style="color: darkgrey;" class="text-left col-md-6">'+item.title_en+'</div></div>');
        $( ".hideDefaultUserLanguage" ).hide();
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="hidedefaultlanguage" class="loadDefaultUserLanguage">
                    <div class="col-md-8 hideDefaultUserLanguage" style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 40px; margin:5px 0px; padding-top:10px;">
                        <div style="color: darkgrey;" class="text-left col-md-6">Select a language</div>
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-right col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I have update my answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidedefaultlanguage" class="loadDefaultUserLanguage">
                    <div class="col-md-8 hideDefaultUserLanguage" style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 40px; margin:5px 0px; padding-top:10px;">
                        <div style="color: darkgrey;" class="text-left col-md-6">Select a language</div>
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-right col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    //Dummy data for this test
var responseDB = {
    selectLanguageRankingTagId: [{
        id: "1",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "English",
        ranking: "2",
        title_en: "English"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "German",
        ranking: "3",
        title_en: "German"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "French",
        ranking: "4",
        title_en: "French"
    }

    ]
}

$.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
        rankingColor = item.ranking;
        if(item.title_en=="English")
        {
        var color="blue";
        } 
        if(item.title_en=="German")
        {
        var color="red";
        } 
        if(item.title_en=="French")
        {
        var color="green";
        } 
        // add the row to the user-language-data div
        $( ".loadDefaultUserLanguage" ).append('<div class="col-md-8" id="del-user-language_' + item.id + '" style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 40px; margin:5px 0px; "><div style="color: darkgrey;background-color:'+color+';height: 40px;width:'+rankingColor+'%;" class="text-left col-md-6">'+item.title_en+'</div></div>');
        $( ".hideDefaultUserLanguage" ).hide();
    });
                    </script>
```

Demo:http://js.do/code/73185

Comment: I have updated section rankingColor = item.ranking * 20; now it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

You should use a HTML class which represents the rank to do this, and then apply CSS accordingly. Also, you should also be using classes/CSS for applying style.

```
$( ".loadDefaultUserLanguage" ).append('<div class="col-md-8 ranking" id="del-user-language_' + item.id + '"><div class="text-left col-md-6 ranking-'+rankingColor+'">'+item.title_en+'</div></div>');
```

And for the `<style>`:

```
.ranking {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 40px;
    margin:5px 0px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.ranking-2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.ranking-3 {
    background-color: red;
}

.ranking-4 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/37/)

Comment: THanks for the reply. Your demos shows colour is changing in full div. My purpose is If rank is 5 then colour fill with full div. Please check the image

Comment: I will explain. Please check my image I am talking about the width of color. If the value is 5 color of width will show full. If ranking is 4 color width will decrease.

Comment: Just add whatever change you need in each class in the CSS, like I did with background-color. It should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need :)

```
$.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
    rankingColor = item.ranking;
    color = '';  
    if(rankingColor == 2){
        color = 'green';
    }
    if(rankingColor == 3){
        color = 'red';
    }
    if(rankingColor == 4){
        color = 'blue';
    }
    // add the row to the user-language-data div
    $( ".loadDefaultUserLanguage" ).append('<div class="col-md-8" id="del-user-language_' + item.id + '" style="background-color: '+color+'; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 40px; margin:5px 0px; padding-top:10px;"><div style="color: darkgrey;" class="text-left col-md-6">'+item.title_en+'</div></div>');
    $( ".hideDefaultUserLanguage" ).hide();
});
```

I edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/31/)

Comment: Thanks but color is showing fully. If you get time please check image I have attached

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple If condition use single Conditional Operator.

```
$.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
    rankingColor = item.ranking;
    color = '';  
    // add the row to the user-language-data div
    $( ".loadDefaultUserLanguage" ).append('<div class="col-md-8" id="del-user-language_' + item.id + '" 

    style="background-color: '+ ((item.title_en=="English") ? 'blue' : ((item.title_en=="German") ? 'red' : 'green'))  +'; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 40px; margin:5px 0px; padding-top:10px;"><div style="color: darkgrey;" class="text-left col-md-6">'+item.title_en+'</div></div>');
    $( ".hideDefaultUserLanguage" ).hide();
});
```

updated [jsfield](http://jsfiddle.net/sankara43/Lr6a5d2v/36/)

Answer (score 0):

sorry. Now try this.

```
    $.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
    rankingColor = (item.ranking) * 20;

    // add the row to the user-language-data div
    $( ".loadDefaultUserLanguage" ).append('<div class="col-md-8" id="del-user-language_' + item.id + '" style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 40px; margin:5px 0px;"><div style="color: darkgrey;background-color:'+ ((item.title_en=="English") ? 'blue' : ((item.title_en=="German") ? 'red' : 'green')) +';height: 40px;width:'+ rankingColor +'%;" class="text-left col-md-6">'+item.title_en+'</div></div>');
    $( ".hideDefaultUserLanguage" ).hide();
});
```

updated [jsfield](http://jsfiddle.net/sankara43/otd3ywcn/1/)